# Count Excel Rows without Opening it

Tags: excel, vba

I've found this Code

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim mypath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim shtname As String
Dim m As Integer
Dim myfile As Workbook

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
.Cells.ClearContents
.Range("A1").Value = "filename"
.Range("B1").Value = "sheet's name"
.Range("C1").Value = "rows count"
End With

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
mypath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

filename = Dir(mypath & "*.xls")
Do While filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open mypath & filename
i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
m = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For j = 1 To i
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
.Cells(m + j, 1).Value = filename
.Cells(m + j, 2).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Name
.Cells(m + j, 3).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
End With
Next j
filename = Dir()
Loop

filename = Dir(mypath & "*.csv")
Do While filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open mypath & filename
m = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
.Cells(m + 1, 1).Value = filename
.Cells(m + 1, 3).Value = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
End With
filename = Dir()
Loop

For Each myfile In Workbooks
If myfile.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
myfile.Close False
End If
Next

End Sub
```

from [chandoo.org](https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-without-opening-an-excel-file.11887/) It counts Rows of Excel without opening it the only problem with this is that it count First Column but i want to count Column (PC) in my excel files
So can any one modify this code to count Column (PC) instead of first Column using Excel Macro

Thanks in Advance

Comment: To down Voters explain why did you down voted?

Comment: Ohhh Sorry my bad column PC or Column number 419

Comment: I did still no luck

Comment: It won't show the files but if you select the folder it will work

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In Column Rows Count

I've improved your code a little.

At the beginning you have **3 important constants** that you have to adjust to your needs:

> - **cVntColumn** - This is the column in which the rows will be counted.    You can use column letter (with quotes e.g. **"PC"**) or number (without quotes e.g. **419**).
>     You currently favorite column is **PC**, so that's what I put in.
> - **cIntHeaderRow** - The Header Row Number is usually the first row with    titles. You maybe don't want to count this row(s) so here you change 
>     it from 0 to what you need. You can have non-contiguous data (data 
>     with empty cells) because the program finds the last row from below.
> - **cBlnHidden** - When enabled, this feature will delete hidden workbooks.    That's what happened to me. I have a hidden workbook
>     always open with    various functions, toolbars etc. And when I ran
>     the original program,    the hidden workbook got closed. You should
>     probably leave it at    False like I'm using it.

---

> **Note:** You must realize that this program opens the workbooks, and in
>   each opened workbook's worksheet calculates the last used row, writes the data to
>   this workbook's **ActiveSheet** and then closes all the workbooks, except this one.

---

```
Sub IncolumnRowsCount()

  Const cVntColumn As Variant = "PC"    ' Count-rows Column Letter/Number
  Const cIntHeaderRow As Integer = 0    ' Header Row Number
  Const cBlnHidden As Boolean = False   ' Enable Close Hidden Workbooks

  ' String Lists
  Const cStrAddresses As String = "A1,B1,C1"
  Const cStrHeaders As String = "FileName,SheetName,Rows"
  Const cStrExtensions As String = "*.xls*,*.csv"
  Const cStrNoWorksheet As String = "*.csv"

  Dim vntAddresses As Variant     ' Addresses Array
  Dim vntHeaders As Variant       ' Headers Array
  Dim vntExt As Variant           ' Extensions Array
  Dim vntNoSheet As Variant       ' No Worksheet Array

  Dim strFolderPath As String     ' Search Folder
  Dim strFileName As String       ' Current File Name (Workbook)
  Dim strWsName As String         ' Current Worksheet
  Dim intSrcCount As Integer      ' Workbooks Count
  Dim intSrcExt As Integer        ' Source File Extensions Counter
  Dim intSrcIndex As Integer      ' Source Worksheets Index
  Dim intSrcNoSheet As Integer    ' Source No Sheet Counter
  Dim lngTgtRow As Long           ' Target Last Row

  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
  End With

  On Error GoTo ProcedureExit

  ' Copy String Lists into arrays.
  vntAddresses = Split(cStrAddresses, ",")
  vntHeaders = Split(cStrHeaders, ",")
  vntExt = Split(cStrExtensions, ",")
  vntNoSheet = Split(cStrExtensions, ",")

  With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet   ' The rest of the code is 'under its wings'.

    ' Prepare Target Worksheet
    .Cells.ClearContents
    For intSrcCount = 0 To UBound(vntAddresses)
      .Range(vntAddresses(intSrcCount)).Value = vntHeaders(intSrcCount)
    Next

    ' Choose Search Folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
      If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
      strFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    ' Loop through extensions.
    For intSrcExt = 0 To UBound(vntExt)

      ' Loop through folder to determine Current File Name (Workbook).
      strFileName = Dir(strFolderPath & vntExt(intSrcExt))

      ' Loop through files in folder.
      Do While strFileName <> ""

        ' Open each file in folder
        Workbooks.Open strFolderPath & strFileName

        ' Calculate last used row of Target Worksheet.
        lngTgtRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, _
            .Range(Trim(vntAddresses(0))).Column).End(xlUp).Row

        For intSrcIndex = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

          ' Write current workbook name to Target Worksheet
          .Cells(lngTgtRow + intSrcIndex, _
              .Range(Trim(vntAddresses(0))).Column).Value = strFileName

          ' If no worksheet (e.g. .csv)
          For intSrcNoSheet = 0 To UBound(vntNoSheet)
            If Trim(vntNoSheet(intSrcNoSheet) = Trim(vntExt(intSrcExt))) _
                Then Exit For
          Next
          ' Write worksheet name to Target Worksheet
          If intSrcNoSheet = UBound(vntNoSheet) + 1 Then .Cells(lngTgtRow + _
              intSrcIndex, .Range(Trim(vntAddresses(1))).Column).Value _
              = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(intSrcIndex).Name

          ' Write the number of records to Target Worksheet. If cIntHeaderRow
          ' is equal to 0, it is also the last used row in Count-row Column.
          .Cells(lngTgtRow + intSrcIndex, _
              .Range(Trim(vntAddresses(2))).Column).Value _
              = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(intSrcIndex) _
              .Cells(Rows.Count, cVntColumn).End(xlUp).Row - cIntHeaderRow
        Next

        strFileName = Dir()
        ' Exclude this workbook.
        If .Parent.Name = strFileName Then strFileName = Dir()

      Loop

    Next

    ' Formatting
    .Columns.AutoFit

    ' Close all open workbooks except this one.
    For intSrcCount = Workbooks.Count To 1 Step -1
      If cBlnHidden Then
        If Workbooks(intSrcCount).Name <> .Parent.Name Then
          Workbooks(intSrcCount).Close False
        End If
       Else
        If Workbooks(intSrcCount).Name <> .Parent.Name And _
          Workbooks(intSrcCount).Windows(1).Visible Then
          Workbooks(intSrcCount).Close False
        End If
      End If
    Next

'     ' ... instead of:
'    Dim objWb As Workbook
'      For Each objWb In Workbooks
'        If objWb.Name <> .Parent.Name Then
'          objWb.Close False
'        End If
'      Next
'    Set objWb = Nothing

  End With

ProcedureExit:

  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
  End With

End Sub
```

---

If you have any other questions about this code, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: It will only bring the last excel file count

Comment: I have a solultion. Need 5 to 10 min.

Comment: Thanks VBasic2008 I will wait

Comment: Sorry it still counts the first column

Comment: I'll write a working program. I'll get back to you in a few days. Cheers.

Comment: it's ok thanks for your help I will Manage with first column

Comment: Wow Great Work thanks. you Covered all the things that are require Thanks for you help

Comment: Thanks for trusting me.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if you mean Column PC which is column 419?

If that is the case you change any applicable place that looks for last row using column 1 to use column 419 or "PC"

E.g.

This

```
m = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Becomes:

```
With ActiveSheet
        m = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "PC").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: Column PC... makes a lot more sense. Hopefully that's it.

Comment: version 2003 and earlier I believe

Comment: Sorry for the sarcasm. There is no version of Excel that has 65536 rows and more than 256 columns (last letter IV). So the logic won't work.

Comment: @VBasic2008 It is the correct specification for <=2003. https://www.itlektor.cz/en/microsoft-excel/excel-limits-specifications/

Comment: you will need to provide more information on what you are trying to achieve. Which column do you want to use to determine last row for starters?

Comment: I have multiple Excel file that I need to Count there "PC" or 419 Column So I search via google and found the above code it dose Count all the excel file in a folder but the problem is that it counts the first column

Comment: well my code will return the row number of the last occupied (not necessarily the count of all occupied) cell in that column.